# Select select query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I achieve this

My first list

```
List<string> lstParams = new List<string> { "Home", "Computer", "Fishing" };
List<string> lstIgnore_If_Have = new List<string> { "me", "hi" };
```

Now I want to check `lstParams` each element and if element have any object of `lstIgnore_If_Have` do not select it.

The result `lstParams` would be as below

**"Computer"**

How to write such linq query ?

I made below but I can't complete it

```
    lstParams = lstParams
    .Where(pr => pr.Contains( lstIgnore_If_Have )) == false).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var v = lstParams.Where (p => ! lstIgnore_If_Have.Any(i=> p.Contains(i)));
```

simply make sure none of the second list is contained in the first one (using the `Any`).
The result is "Computer".

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
lstParams = lstParams.Where( x => lstIgnore_If_Have.All( s => !x.Contains( s ) ))
                     .ToList();
```